# Query for aceesing latest dates records

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

my table

```
id  home  datetime     player   resource
---|-----|------------|--------|---------
1  | 10  | 04/03/2009 | john   | 399 
2  | 11  | 04/03/2009 | juliet | 244
5  | 12  | 04/03/2009 | borat  | 555
3  | 10  | 03/03/2009 | john   | 300
4  | 11  | 03/03/2009 | juliet | 200
6  | 12  | 03/03/2009 | borat  | 500
7  | 13  | 24/12/2008 | borat  | 600
8  | 13  | 01/01/2009 | borat  | 700
```

The result would be selecting all the records between newest 2 dates how to write query for this

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Tag dbms used! (Neither MySQL nor MS SQL Server are ANSI SQL compliant when it comes to date/time...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `DENSE_RANK` for this:

```
SELECT id, home, [datetime], player, resource
FROM (
  SELECT id, home, [datetime], player, resource,
         DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY [datetime] DESC) AS rnk
  FROM mytable) AS t
WHERE t.rnk <= 2
```

`DENSE_RANK` assigns a value of 1 to all records related to the *newest* date value and a value of 2 to all records related to the *second newest* date value.

**Output:**

```
id  home    datetime            player  resource
=================================================
7   13  2009-12-12 02:00:00.000 borat   600
1   10  2009-04-03 03:00:00.000 john    399
2   11  2009-04-03 03:00:00.000 juliet  244
5   12  2009-04-03 03:00:00.000 borat   555
```

In MySQL you can simulate `DENSE_RANK` using variables:

```
SELECT id, `datetime`, player, resource
FROM (
  SELECT id, `datetime`, player, resource,
         @rn := IF(@dt = `datetime`, @rn, 
                   IF(@dt := `datetime`, @rn + 1, @rn + 1)) AS rnk
  FROM mytable
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rn := 0, @dt := '1900-01-01') AS vars
  ORDER BY `datetime` DESC) AS t
WHERE t.rnk <= 2
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fb049/3)

Comment: @EdwinBaby No, window functions are not available in MySQL.

Comment: can you please tell me how to do same functionality in Mysql

Comment: row_number () can only issue one value of 1 per partition. Rank () or dense_rank () can issue more than one instance of any value per partition.

Comment: @Edwin Baby: You said you are using SQL Server, so you should use the DENSE_RANK solution. What do you need the MySQL solution for?